# How can i get information from the front-end (react) and use it in the backend (node.js) to send sms using twilio?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, http, twilio-api

I made service website and i want to use the information from the cart to send a sms confirming that the form they filled put and the products and services they selected. I would also like to receive that same information.

I only have server that is listening at port: 5000

```
const express = require('express');
const accountSid = process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID;
const authToken = process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN;
const  client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);
require('dotenv').config();
const app = express();
const port = 5000;

app.get('/', (req, res) => {

  sendTextMessages();
  res.send(`
  <div style='text-align: center; padding-top:40px'>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    <p>This is a sample page</p>
  </div>
  `);
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});

function sendTextMessages() {}

/////////Cart.jsx////////
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import CartItems from '../components/CartItems/CartItems';
import CartForm from '../components/CartForm/CartForm';

const Cart = () => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({});
  const [cartData, setCartData] = useState([]);

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    // Here, you can send the formData and cartData to your server or perform any other action you need.
    // You can access formData and cartData to submit the data.
    console.log('Form Data:', formData);
    console.log('Cart Data:', cartData);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <CartForm setFormData={setFormData} />
      <CartItems setCartData={setCartData} />
      <button style={{
    backgroundColor: '#ff5a5a',
    color: '#fff',
    border: 'none',
    padding: '20px 60px', // Increase padding for a larger button
    borderRadius: '5px',
    cursor: 'pointer',
    display: 'block',     // Center horizontally
    margin: '0 auto',     // Center horizontally
    fontSize: '18px',
  }} onClick={handleSubmit}>Get Free Estimate</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Cart;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why you use Frontend and backend in the same file?
separate the frontend and backend and communicate with them using `Axios`
search about how you can build REST API and how to hit the end points from the frontend using `Axios`

- If you want to make the frontend and the backend in the same project you can use `ejs` for server-side rendering, search about MVC in node.js using Express.js and `.ejs`

Comment: okay thank you. I will do my research.